# Transferring Android Project to Git private server

Tags: android, git, version-control

I want to add an android project to a git private server.

I set up git on the private server and now I want to add my android project to this git server.

Before I added this project in local GitLab but now I should change the location.
My problem is that I don't know how to add my project to the new server while all of the changes and repositories transfer into the new server.

I just have the address of the server for transferring.
Do I need something else?
Can I add my project to the private server?

Answer (score 0):

If you have created a new empty bare repository on the new private Git server, you can use your local cloned repository to:

- switch its remote `origin` to reference the new private server
- push everything

That is:

```
cd /path/to/my/cloned/repository
git remote set-url origin /url/new/private/server/myEmptyRepo
git push --mirror
```

The URL of the new private server and the way you setup a new empty repository there depend on the nature of said private Git server.

Comment: Thanks @VonC. Is the first command means the path of the project on my local computer?

Comment: @Fahim Yes: local clone means cloning the original remote repository locally on your computer.

Comment: Should I write these commands in Git bash? I've written this in Git bash but cd 'path of the project' shows "No such file or directory"!

Comment: If you are on Windows, you can use a simple CMD. A `cd C:\path\my\cloned\repo` will work, provided you did clone the repository first.